# How to inherit ElementTree.Element class in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, elementtree

I try to define a NewElement class, which inherit ElementTree.Element. The goal is adding a few more methods, e.g. foo1(), foo2(), to it.

**Define NewElement class:**
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

```
class NewElement(ET.Element):
    def __init__(self):
        # Q1: how to init ET.Element? refer to ET's refer guide - http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement
        pass
    def foo1(self):
        # do something on Element
        return self
    def foo2(self):
        # do something else on Element
        return self
```

**Want to use NewElement in such a way:**

```
a_element = ET.fromstring(xmlstring)    # Q2: how to generate a NewElement object instead of ET.Element one
a_element.foo1().foo2()     # this is my goal to easier use foo1, foo2 functions
```

**The questions are**

**Q1 -** how to init NewElement's parent? the ET's reference guide saide ET.Element can be initialized but it seems only the element itself without children.

**Q2 -** other ET's class/function returns Element, but I expect NewElement. Do I need change all of them?

Do I on the right direction to reach my goal? Or use multiple inheritance instead? Or use mixin? How? ...

Thank you for you great inputs.

Answer (score 0):

It's unnecessary to do so. Simply make `foo1` `foo2` *module level* functions which accept instances of `Element` and return the instances:

```
foo2(foo1(a_element))
```

Comment: thanks. As you know, aNewElement.foo1().foo2() feels good than foo2(foo1(a_element). It is neat usage - aNewElement.foo1(argv1, ....).foo2(argvx....). Now I am seeking mixin to resolve this.