# Inherit or mock pythons etree.ElementTree.Element possible?

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I'm trying to create a small addon for `ElementTree` and `Element` in python's `xml.etree.ElementTree` which would allow for notation like:

```
root = ET.fromstring('<root><a><b attr1="2"/></a></root>')
element1 = root.a
element2 = root.a.b
attr = root.a.b.attr
```

I've tried this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as _ET

def __getattr__(self, key):
    return self.find('./' + key)

class ElementTree(_ET.ElementTree):
    __getattr__ = __getattr__


class Element(_ET.Element):
    __getattr__ = __getattr__
```

But this does not work because `ET.parse`, `ET.fromstring`, `ET.ElementTree.find` etc will always return the internal `Element` and `ElementTree` objects.

Monkeypatching the classes does not work either:

```
>>> xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.__getattr__ = lambda x: x
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-bacb0a64c2e5> in <module>()
----> 1 xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.__getattr__ = lambda x: x

TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'
```

Is this doable without copying the python etree module and then adding `__getattr__`?

Related: [How to inherit ElementTree.Element class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243529/how-to-inherit-elementtree-element-class-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding the class is not possible due to [import of the Element and XMLParser's C implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L1653-1663):

```
# Import the C accelerators
try:
    # Element is going to be shadowed by the C implementation. We need to keep
    # the Python version of it accessible for some "creative" by external code
    # (see tests)
    _Element_Py = Element

    # Element, SubElement, ParseError, TreeBuilder, XMLParser
    from _elementtree import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

The module `_elementtree` is found in [Modules/_elementtree.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_elementtree.c).

A solution would be to copy the python etree module, and change the import to:

```
_Element_Py = Element
```

I made a simple implementation of this: https://github.com/arve0/objectifiedetree

Use like this:

```
from objectifiedetree import *

tree = ET.parse('/path/to/file.xml')
# dot notation :-)
el = tree.xpath.to.your.element

# use normal etree attributes
print(el.attrib)

# access name crashes
attrib_el = el.find('./attrib')
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I accidentally found a quick workaround:
I imported `xmlschema` in a version prior to Python 3.7 and had no issues monkeypatching `ET.Element` with `setattr`.

EDIT: As this was intriguing I have since looked into it further. Here is [how to monkeypatch ElementTree](https://blog.matteoferla.com/2019/02/uniprot-xml-and-python-elementtree.html).